# Combine SetSourceData ranges

Tags: vba, excel

please help with my Object required error

```
Dim MyRange As Range

With Sheets("DATA")

 Set ChartRange251 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "P"), .Cells(NumFlds, "P"))
 ChartRange251Addr = ChartRange251.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange252 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AB"), .Cells(NumFlds,"AB"))
 ChartRange252Addr = ChartRange252.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange253 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AC"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AC"))
 ChartRange253Addr = ChartRange253.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange254 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AD"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AD"))
 ChartRange254Addr = ChartRange254.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange255 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AE"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AE"))
 ChartRange255Addr = ChartRange255.Address(External:=True)

 Set ChartRange256 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AF"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AF"))
 ChartRange256Addr = ChartRange256.Address(External:=True)

End With

Sheets("DrillDown").ChartObjects("Chart 25").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Union(ChartRange251Addr, ChartRange252Addr, ChartRange253Addr, ChartRange254Addr, ChartRange255Addr, ChartRange256Addr)
```

The error is occurring on the last line

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Union(ChartRange251Addr, ChartRange252Addr, ChartRange253Addr, ChartRange254Addr, ChartRange255Addr, ChartRange256Addr)`

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that method will work at all, but in your code you are trying to use the Union of a series of strings whereas it should be ranges, `ChartRange251` rather than `ChartRange251Addr`.

Comment: @Damian M it seems you haven't found the time (as I seen from previous posts you psoted on  **SO**) to give proper feedback to posts that were helpful. Read this :https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Damian M to accept as "ANSWER" you need to click the gray check-mark on the left side of the post that answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Application.Union` expects a `Range`, not a `String` as in [MSDN Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel)

Also, you are using `With` statements so nicely in your code, why ruin it with

```
Sheets("DrillDown").ChartObjects("Chart 25").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
```

And

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData
```

Instead of using `Activate` and `Select` just fully qualify your `ChartObject`.

***Modified Code***

```
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

With Sheets("DATA")
    Set ChartRange251 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "P"), .Cells(NumFlds, "P"))

    Set ChartRange252 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AB"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AB"))

    Set ChartRange253 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AC"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AC"))

    Set ChartRange254 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AD"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AD"))

    Set ChartRange255 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AE"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AE"))

    Set ChartRange256 = .Range(.Cells(NumFlds2, "AF"), .Cells(NumFlds, "AF"))
End With

' set the chart object range
Set ChtObj = Sheets("DrillDown").ChartObjects("Chart 25")

With ChtObj
    .Chart.SetSourceData Union(ChartRange251, ChartRange252, ChartRange253, ChartRange254, ChartRange255, ChartRange256)
End With
```